# Why can't I override the * method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a [Ruby Gem for creating presentations](https://rubygems.org/gems/presentation), and I would like to create a syntax for defining slides that is simple and intuitive. I'm making use of `instance_eval` so I can call methods on self. Here's what I originally planned to do:

```
slide {
  title 'What is Ruby?'
  * 'a programming language'
  * 'with lots of interpreters'
  * 'lots of fun!'
}
```

Even though I've defined a `*` method, I get the error:

> in `instance_eval': ... syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError)

I have compromised by creating a short method called `b` for creating bullets, but it's not as nice:

```
slide {
  title 'What is Ruby?'
  b 'a programming language'
  b 'with lots of interpreters'
  b 'lots of fun!'
}
```

Is this just a limitation of the interpreter? Or is there a way to get around it?

**Update:** If you want, you can dig into the [full source code](https://github.com/andrewhavens/presentation), but here is a small example of how it is implemented:

```
class Slide
  attr_accessor :title, :bullets
end

class SlidesDSL
  attr_accessor :slides
  def slide
    @slides ||= []
    s = SlideDSL.new
    s.instance_eval(&block)
    @slides << s.slide
  end
  class SlideDSL
    def slide
      @slide ||= Slide.new
    end

    def title(text)
      slide.title
    end

    def *(text)
      bullet(text)
    end

    def b(text)
      slide.bullets ||= []
      slide.bullets << text
    end
  end
end

# load_slides_from_file
source = File.read(filename)
dsl = SlidesDSL.new
dsl.instance_eval(source, filename, 0)
@slides = dsl.slides
```

Comment: The information you provide is not enough to tell the cause of the error.

Comment: *How* did you define it? You can *define* it easily, but it's an operator, so it depends on how you defined it, and how your DSL works.

Comment: I just added an update with a sample of the source code

Comment: You can try create method `-@` for strings inside your block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that you are relying on syntactic sugar that is given to the
>   * method for many things.

That's not the case.  You can do this:

```
class Dog

  private
  def do_stuff(arg)
    puts 2 + arg
  end

end

d = Dog.new

d.instance_eval do
  do_stuff(3) 
end

--output:--
5
```

1. `instance_eval()` changes self to its receiver, `d` in this case.
2. In Ruby, `private` only means you cannot call the method with an explicit receiver.
3. A method call without an explicit receiver implicitly uses self as the receiver.

Now if you change the method's name from `do_stuff` to `*`:

```
class Dog

  private
  def *(arg)
    puts 2 + arg
  end

end

d = Dog.new

d.instance_eval do
  *(3)
end

--output:--
1.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
```

So the op is relying on normal method operation, not any syntactic sugar attributed to `*`.  Inside the `instance_eval` block, you would expect Ruby to implicitly execute:

```
self.*(3)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
d.*(3)
```

Comment: I was not talking about any syntactic sugar related to the eval or instance_eval, only in the means that there are no '.' characters there.  And the OP, in my observation, may be fighting the mechanisms given to + and * for example in normal method calls.  In that other methods if they are at the end of the line don't suggest other things to come, but can be the line terminator.

Comment: @Confusion, I think your comment is very informative.  I tried to move your comment under your post, and then delete my post, but the system wouldn't let me delete my post.

Comment: You are right, that comment serves better as an expansion on my answer; moved it there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a limitation of the Ruby grammar. Specifically, you cannot, as sawa points out, use it with an implicit receiver (nor turn into a unary operator): it expects something on the left hand side.

All operators are simply methods called on the object referenced before it, but some operators are more equal than others. Most methods accept an implicit receiver, but the one named `*` doesn't.

I opted for `o` in a similar situation.

-- Added later (as I originally commented on 7stud's post):

The problem is that the Ruby parser (Yacc grammar + a bunch of methods) simply does not allow a line starting with a * to be parsed such that the * denotes a method call. If a line starts with a *, the only possible parsing is one where the * is the 'splat' operator. This limitation is unique to the * character used as a method name.

Comment: The code in the block doesn't make it past the parser. There is no receiver, because there is no method call.

Comment: @sawa Are you sure? `*` is special because of splat. You could define `+@` or `-@` and it would work fine, but asterisk is different and AFAIK you can't define it as a unary operator.

Comment: @spike Except that `*` will look for `to_ary` then `to_a` (IIRC), so there are likely some playable games along those lines.

Comment: @spike As I wrote, it is not working as a unary operator here. And you seem to be confusing it with prepended unary operators.

Comment: Note: I removed the mention of unary operators, because it is indeed irrelevant. My point was that the * operator always needs an explicit left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

If instead of using `*`, you are willing to use `-` (or `+`), you can achieve a very similar result by overloading the unary minus (or plus) operators on `String`. The following code automatically defines, and undefines unary `-` on string, so it works during the block but doesn't change any definition when the block is finished. Note that  if a method is called inside the block, the `-` will still use the custom behaviour. This isn't much of an issue though, as there isn't a default definition for unary `-` for Strings. It could also be useful for extracting common code.

```
class Slide
  attr_accessor :title, :bullets
end

class SlidesDSL
  attr_accessor :slides
  def slide(&block)
    @slides ||= []
    s = SlideDSL.new
    old_unary_minus = String.instance_method(:-@) rescue nil
    begin
      String.send(:define_method, :-@) do
        s.b(self)
      end
      s.instance_eval(&block)
    ensure
      String.send(:remove_method, :-@)
      if old_unary_minus
        String.send(:define_method, :-@) do
          old_unary_minus.bind(self).call
        end
      end
    end
    @slides << s.slide
  end
  class SlideDSL
    def slide
      @slide ||= Slide.new
    end

    def title(text)
      slide.title = text
    end

    def *(text)
      bullet(text)
    end

    def b(text)
      slide.bullets ||= []
      slide.bullets << text
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
SlidesDSL.new.slide do
  title "Some title"
  - "one value"
  - "another value"
  4.times do |i|
    - "repeated value #{i}"
  end
end
```

Returns:

```
[#<Slide:0x007f99a194d0f8 @bullets=["one value", "another value", "repeated value 0", "repeated value 1", "repeated value 2", "repeated value 3"], @title="Some title">]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Question: why do define the method like this: `:-@` and not like `:-`?

Comment: @Andrew: Because `:-` is the binary minus operator. Ie the expression `"this" - "that"` is equivalent to `"this".send(:-, "that")`, while `-"string"` is equivalent to `"string".send(:-@)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `*` method has to be "anti-private". With the predefined method `*` on numerals, you can observe this.

```
3.instance_eval{*}      # => syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting '='
3.instance_eval{*()}    # => syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
3.instance_eval{self.*} # => wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

It looks like `*` is hard-wired to require an explicit receiver.

Comment: `ruby -e 'class A; def *(x); 2 + x; end; end; puts A.new * 5'` outputs `7`. It's perfectly possible to override the * method as a public method in any class.

Comment: @Confusion I don't see how your example is related to whether `*` is a public method.

Comment: In my example, `*` is a public method?

Comment: @Confusion I see. It is used as a public method. But that is irrelevant to my point. My point concerns whether it can be used as a private method. Whether it can be a public method is irrelevant.

Comment: From an earlier version of your answer I got the impression you suggested that the `*` method needed to be private. However, I think it doesn't matter anyway: as you say `It looks like * is hard-wired to require an explicit receiver.`.

Comment: It turned out to be the opposite of that. `*` cannot be private.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why you are calling `instance_eval` on integers.  Not sure that was specified that the class was going to be of that type.

Comment: @vgoff I answered this before the OP showed the relevant code. I was showing some property of  `*` by using a class that already has `*` defined. The content of the definition is irrelevant.

Comment: It was confusing, looked like it was changed from being a bullet point to being a method call.  So from 1.) <method call> to 1.<method call>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are relying on syntactic sugar that is given to the * method for many things.

If you write your `*` method and use it with the implicit `.` to indicate it is a message to the receiver, you may have better luck.

For instance, when I do this with `Fixnum`

```
class Fixnum
  def *
    "This is the modified star"
  end
end
```

When I try this in IRB

```
>> 1 * 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I would also get the normal problem of having it recognize the `*` if I were to simply press enter... it would expect more input on the next line...

However, if I do this:

```
>> 1.*
=> ""This is the modified star"
```

So it isn't that it is impossible to do, you may just be fighting with syntactic sugar that evolves around this particular symbol.

Consider the private method, which you can do, but you would have difficulties using the 'eval' family of calls.  You could instead do this:

```
some_instance.send(:*)
```

If, of course, there is an argument needed, we can do `some_instance.send(:*, argument)`

Comment: I posted a response to your post.

Comment: Thanks @7stud replied in comment to your answer.